# Delphi XE5 DBExpress MS Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, dbexpress

I am using the DBExpress components that ship with Delphi XE5. The database connection only have drivers for MySQL, SQLite, Interbase. Is there a way to connect this components to a MS Access database? If yes, how?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use the Ado components instead?

Comment: Thank you to MartynA and RRUZ for their contribution but I would prefer to use the "disconnected technology" that comes with the DBExpress components, if possible. Thank you for your replies.